# gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, build, xcode3.2

I'm working with Xcode 3.2.3 and iOS 4.0.1 and I have downloaded an open source iPhone game to learn from but without editing anything I tried to run it in the simulator and it throws this error message:

> ```
>     ProcessPCH /var/folders/-r/-r6hd0CEEASnoGYBU9KSlk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/catchcat_Prefix-crjsognppahnfgdfvinmsqvdioie/catchcat_Prefix.pch.gch
> ```
>
> catchcat_Prefix.pch normal i386
>   objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
>       cd "/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20"
>       setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=30200 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk
>   -fvisibility=hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote "/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/catchcat-generated-files.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/catchcat-own-target-headers.hmap"
>   "-I/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/catchcat-all-target-headers.hmap"
>   -iquote "/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/catchcat-project-headers.hmap"
>   "-F/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/Debug-iphonesimulator"
>   "-I/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include"
>   "-I/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/DerivedSources/i386"
>   "-I/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open
>   Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/build/catchcat.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/catchcat.build/DerivedSources"
>   -c "/Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open Source
>   iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/catchcat_Prefix.pch" -o /var/folders/-r/-r6hd0CEEASnoGYBU9KSlk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/catchcat_Prefix-crjsognppahnfgdfvinmsqvdioie/catchcat_Prefix.pch.gch
>
> ```
> i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/ryanpoolos/Desktop/Open Source
> ```
>
> iPhone/lifengtian-catchcat-f3d5f20/catchcat_Prefix.pch: No such file or directory
>       i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: warning: '-x objective-c-header' after
>   last input file has no effect
>       i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
>       Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Help me out anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something somewhere isn't properly quoting the spaces in your path.  Try renaming `OPen Source iPhone` to `OpenSourceIPhone` or something.

Silly, I know, but occasionally the unixisms creep through.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have an empty line in any of configuration lists of the project. For example in user defines or include paths.